# Multiplo insert com laravel 5.3 formulário dinâmico

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3

Estou tentando fazer um multiplo insert com `Laravel 5.3` numa tabela como segue:

**`Form`**

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'demanda.store', 'class' => 'form']) !!}
<div class="form-group form-inline">
  {!! Form::label('ano', 'Ano:'); !!}
  {!! Form::text('ano', $ano, ['class'=>'form-control','readonly']); !!}    
</div>
<div class="form-group form-inline">
  @foreach ($unidades as $unidade)
    <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::hidden('item_id[]', $items->id, null); !!}
      {!! Form::hidden('ano[]', $ano); !!}
      {!! Form::label('unidade', $unidade->sigla); !!}
      {!! Form::hidden('unidade_id[]', $unidade->id, null); !!}
      {!! Form::text('qtd[]', null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder' =>'Demanda'])!!}
    </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
{!! Form::submit('Salvar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Como ficaria meu controller para inserir esses dados na minha tabela, sabendo que os campos da minha tabela são:

> - `ano`
> - `tem_id`
> - `unidade_id`
> - `qtd`

**`Controller`**

```
public function store(DemandaFormRequest $request)
{
    $dataForm = $request->all();
    $insert = $this->demanda->insert($dataForm);
 }
```

Recebo o seguinte **erro**:

> `QueryException in Connection.php line 770: Array to string conversion`

Comment: É por alguns campos do teu form chegarem como array, deves fazer um foreach para inserires cada um

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um `array` de ***informações*** para ser gravado com [laravel-eloquent](/questions/tagged/laravel-eloquent), precisa ser feito um `for` para cada **item** e grava **um** a **um** da seguinte forma:

```
public function store(DemandaFormRequest $request)
{
    $dataForm = $request->all();
    for($i = 0; $i<count($dataForm['ano']); $i++)
    {
        // gerando os dados, foi feito isso porque existe um campo 
        // que é diferente no form e na tabela, 
        // se não gravaria o $item direto
        // talvez caiba uma alteração no form (alerta) pois ai o trabalho
        // seria menor
        if (isset($dataForm['qtde']) && !is_null($dataForm['qtde'][$i])) 
        {
            $arrayForm = array(
             'ano' => $dataForm['ano'][$i],
             'tem_id' => $dataForm['item_id'][$i],
             'unidade_id' => $dataForm['unidade_id'][$i], 
             'qtd' => $dataForm['qtde'][$i]
            );
        }
        //imagino que demanda é um instância do Eloquent
        if (count($arrayForm) > 0) 
        {
           $this->demanda->create($arrayForm); // criando novos registros.
        }
    }
}
```

Vale lembrar que [`DB`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database) tem a opção desejada para gravar um `array` de informações seguindo essa idéia:

```
public function store(DemandaFormRequest $request)
{
    $dataForm = $request->all();
    for($i = 0; $i<count($dataForm['ano']); $i++)
    {
        // gerando os dados, foi feito isso porque existe um campo 
        // que é diferente no form e na tabela, 
        // se não gravaria o $item direto
        // talvez caiba uma alteração no form (alerta) pois ai o trabalho
        // seria menor
        if (isset($dataForm['qtde']) && !is_null($dataForm['qtde'][$i])) 
        {
            $arrayForm[] = array(
             'ano' => $dataForm['ano'][$i],
             'tem_id' => $dataForm['item_id'][$i],
             'unidade_id' => $dataForm['unidade_id'][$i], 
             'qtd' => $dataForm['qtde'][$i]
            );
        }
    }
    if (count($arrayForm) > 0) 
    { 
        \DB::table('demanda')->insert($arrayForm); 
    }
}
```

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [Database: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database)
- [Database: Inserts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#inserts)
- [Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent)

Comment: Recebo o seguinte erro: Illegal string offset 'ano' caso retire a variável ano, o erro pula para a próxima.

Comment: at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'Illegal string offset 'ano'', 'C:\wamp64\www\siscarp-laravel\app\Http\Controllers\Demanda\DemandasController.php', '91', array('request' => object(Request), 'dataForm' => array('_token' => 'zDgdJebBqCWXDvkUy0ZXxCR22A2Y5OFKsEdBGDNL', 'ano' => array('2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017'), 'item_id' => array('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'), 'unidade_id' => array('6', '8', '5', '7', '3', '2', '1', '15', '9', '11', '10', '13', '14'

Comment: Eu fiz uma edição, verifique! @JoséCiceroRochaCavalcante

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente.